# How can I get back Java Preferences after uninstalling JDK 7 on Mac

Tags: mac, java, jdk

When I installed Oracle's JDK 7 on Mac (OSX 10.8), Java Preferences disappeared.

Now I removed JDK 7, and reinstalled Apple's JDK 6, but still, I don't have Java Preferences in Applications/Utilities

How can I install it back?